# ASP.NET MVC DB First create dynamic dbcontext

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC and I have created two dbcontext (for 2016 and 2017) with DB first approach, and I will access this, depending on the year parameter

In web.config:

```
<add name="DB2016Context" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model2016.csdl|res://*/Models.Model2016.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model2016.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=DBSource;initial catalog=DB2016;persist security info=True;user id=xx;password=xx;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
<add name="DB2017Context" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Model2017.csdl|res://*/Models.Model2017.ssdl|res://*/Models.Model2017.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=DBSource;initial catalog=DB2017;persist security info=True;user id=xx;password=xx;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

I have create model MyDbContext.cs

```
public DbMyContext(int year)
            : base("name=DB" + year + "Context") 
        { }
```

For use

```
    DbMyContext dbSelected = new DbMyContext(year);
    DbSet<Models.Tab1> tab1 = dbSelected.Set<Models.Tab1>();
            using (dbSelected)
            {
                var query = (from a in tab1 
                             where a.YEAR== year
                             orderby a.NAME
                             select new { a.ID, a.YEAR, a.NAME }).Distinct();
```

My problem: every year a new database is created, the same structure, and my application should dynamically create a dbcontext to connect to each one, without I have to go manually to create it.

I apologize if I have not been fairly clear.
Thanks

Comment: To dynamically generate `DBContext`, you need to generate the corresponding EF `connectionString` and write it to `appSettings`. Hints to sight: `OpenWebConfiguration` & `EntityConnectionStringBuilder` (with current provided code your intent still unclear).

Comment: You mean to add string in web.config equal to those already present but with different year? es. <add name="DBnewYearContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.ModelnewYear.csdl|res://*/Models.ModelnewYear.ssdl|res://*/Models.ModelnewYear.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=DBSource;initial catalog=DBnewYear;persist security info=True;user id=xx;password=xx;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

Comment: Yes, it was what I think now. I want to know how newly created database (either manually or programmatically) after changing year bound to EF's data context by defining `EntityConnectionStringBuilder` for that DB (also generating data model classes from it).

Comment: the new db is manually created by others, so the application must have a select from which to select the years related to the db, and allow it to connect to it for query.  But how do I create data model classes for each db with EntityConnectionStringBuilder? Thanks for your help

Comment: Well, since the DB is manually created, you can use `DateTime.Now.Year` to create year digits & use `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` to create standard SQL Server connection. Then, create an EF connection using `EntityConnectionStringBuilder`, save them both in web.config & create new `DbContext` from EF connection (may requires a check to see if the corresponding database exists).

Comment: I did everything you said to me: create standard SQL Server connection, create an EF connection using EntityConnectionStringBuilder, save them both in web.config. I used this code [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.data.entityclient.entityconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx) but when I open the connection I get this error: "Unable to load the specified metadata resource".

Comment: I wrote entityBuilder.Metadata = @"res://*/Models.Model" + anno + @".csdl|
                                       res://*/Models.Model" + anno + @".ssdl|
                                       res://*/Models.Model" + anno + @".msl";

Comment: Yes, I wrote at the end of my msg: "Unable to load the specified metadata resource".

Comment: I think you're not generating the CSDL, SSDL & MSL related components for the target DB yet, try reviewing this article: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/67b85026-4e89-4be5-8734-4b3dbf7cc1ac/create-metamodel-at-runtime-and-then-generate-edmx-file-?forum=adodotnetentityframework. The common way is either using CodeDom or generate model classes at runtime.

Comment: I'm also looking for google examples to understand the whole process but I can not find anything. I think it's too hard for a newbie like me!

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Code First](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620(v=vs.113).aspx) approach. You'll find soon that it's much more convenient.

Comment: Sure. Just generate initial model using this database.

Comment: Then you can turn off model checking, if you are sure that it does not change.

Comment: so if I understand well before I should create classes with db first and then turn off model? Can you add more details on how to do it? thank you

Comment: You can't turn off the model, cause you need it to access the database. You can turn off model checking for ignoring database changes. Open the link in my answer. It should be a good start.